# React navigation.navigate for prop drilling

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a form consisting of multiple screens that will require adding data to an object. This object is to be submitted at the end of the form. There are of course multiple ways for prop drilling to the final page. One method is to use the UseContext hook, but would it also be legitimate to use navigation.navigate(route, {params}) for prop drilling? I found this a much easier way to do the task without writing much extra code.

Comment: Pardon me, but your question has not a single question mark in it. What are you trying to ask exactly? How to avoid prop drilling? `React.context` is one way to deal with prop drilling. For forms specifically you can try using `Formik` (https://formik.org/docs/overview)

Comment: Sorry, just edited the question.

Comment: I see. I'd advise not doing that, the navigation parameters should be used for what they're meant, as parameters you need to for navigation purposes. Using it to save state will create an unimaginable mess (imagine having to manage state that's part where it's supposed to be and part in the navigation parameters...). Use one of the solutions I suggested in my previous message, I think they fit your use case best.

Comment: Thanks a lot, [Formik] is just what I was looking for.